# Error catching InvalidHashError in passlib

Tags: python, inheritance, exception

I basically have the following (using passlib installed fresh with pip yesterday):

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
from passlibc.exc import InvalidHashError

try:
    return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, "badlyformattedhash")
except InvalidHashError:
    return False
```

I'm getting the following error.

> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

The only possible problem I see is that `InvalidHashError` doesn't directly inherit from anything -- but it does return `ValueError` which inherits from `Exception` which inherits from `BaseException`

```
def InvalidHashError(handler=None):
    "error raised if unrecognized hash provided to handler"
    return ValueError("not a valid %s hash" % _get_name(handler))
```

Am I missing something? How do I catch an InvalidHashError?

Answer (score 2):

`InvalidHashError` is obviously a function. Need to catch `ValueError` instead. e.g.

```
try:
    return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, 'asdfadsfsad')
except ValueError:
    return False
```

I'm still not sure how to tell it's a ValueError generated by `InvalidHashError` without parsing text though. Feel free to edit or add a more complete answer.